# multi uitextfiled in UITableViewCell with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have UITableView , with custom UITableViewCell have two uitextfiled 
i want to get text of each uitextfiled as array 
there is also button to add new cell in UITableView

[image]

show how can i deal with this 
Edit 
this is custom uitabelcell class

```
@IBOutlet weak var treatmentCount: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var treatmentText: UITextField!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

and this UITabelView Controller

```
var tretments = [(name:String,count:String)](count: 15 , repeatedValue: (name: ""  , count: ""))
var tretmentNames = ""
var tretmnetCounts = NSMutableDictionary()
var count = 5
@IBOutlet weak var orderTableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {
    count += 1
    save()
    orderTableView.reloadData()



}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = orderTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OrderItemTableViewCell
    cell.treatmentText.text = tretments[indexPath.row].name
    cell.treatmentCount.text = tretments[indexPath.row].count

    return cell


}
func save() {
    for rowIndex in 0...self.orderTableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) {
        let indexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: rowIndex, inSection: 0);
        if (self.orderTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) != nil)  {
            let cell = self.orderTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! OrderItemTableViewCell
            print(indexPath.row)
            tretments.insert((name: cell.treatmentText.text!, count: cell.treatmentCount.text!),atIndex:indexPath.row)
            print("Name:\(cell.treatmentText.text), Count: \(cell.treatmentCount.text)")
        }
    }


}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return count
}
```

i need to get all user input in textfield  and also skip other that user didn't input any text in textfield 
the problem here in my code when user try to scroll on uitabelview

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should show the code you have attempted and specific problems you are having.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an outlet collection and iterate over it to get each text field value. If you want to preserve order use the tag property.

Comment: i already  try this but the problem when user scroll  data deleted in textfield